# How to find integers that can be expressed both as $ay$ and as $x^2+bx + c$

Tags: calculus, number-theory

How to find positive integers that can be expressed both as $ay$ and as $x^2+bx + c$ where $a,b,c,x,y$ are positive integers and $b,c,y$ are constants? Also I am not interesting in the value of $a$, just $x$.

I been trying to use(More like understand) the [Integer relation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm) for solving this, but I don't see how it can help.

Is there a way of solving this?

Comment: This is not clear.  Every integer can be written that way for suitable $a,y,x,b,c$.  I imagine that some of these are specified in advance....which ones?

Comment: @lulu tnx, only now I see how unclear it was. I hope you understand the question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes down to a quadratic congruence. Assume $y,b,c$ are specified integers.  Then an integer $N$ is expressible in both forms iff we can find an integer $a$ such that $x^2 +bx +(c-ay)$ has integer roots.  But this comes down to asking for an integer $a$ such that $\sqrt {b^2-4(c-ay)}$ is integral.  Thus you ask that we can solve the congruence $$M^2\equiv b^2-4c\mod (4y)$$  That is, you want $b^2-4c$ to be a quadratic residue mod($4y$).

Comment: Assuming that there is at-least one solution, how can I find all the rest of the $x$, that will give a solution. I been trying this with $b=3,c=6$ and $y=5$, I tested the first 1000 values and it looks like the solution is $f(n) = 5n + 1$ Where f(n) is all the possible values for $x$

Comment: to solve these problems practically, write out the quadratic congruence you want.  In your case we have $x^2+3x+6\equiv 0\mod (5)$.  Solve that just by checking each residue class.  As you say, the only solution here is $x\equiv 1\mod (5)$.  It will always come down to congruences like that.